# How to send a document from a document library directly as attachment?

Tags: document-library, email, sandbox-solution

Is there a way to change the behavior of the "send to"-drop-down in a DL from "E-Mail a link" to "E-Mail as attachment"?

Comment: SmtpClient is not available from a sandboxed solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/1def68eb-85e4-43f1-bbfc-ffe5871c5b2c/ SPUtility.SendEmail() doesn't allow attachments either. @Flash265 did you find an appropriate workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send a document as an attachment, you will need to write custom code. Use a feature to create a custom action that adds the "Send as attachment" link to the ECM.

```
<UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/MyApp/MyCustomPage.aspx?ItemId={ItemId}&amp;ListId={ListId}" />
```

Clicking this menu item navigates to a custom application page where the user enters the email address/subject/email-body. The code-behind constructs the email and creates the attachment based on the current item and then sends the email.

```
using System.Net.Mail;

// get current list and item from query string
string listId = Request.QueryString["ListId"];
SPList list = this.Web.Lists[new Guid(listId)];
string itemId = Request.QueryString["ItemId"];
SPListItem item = list.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(itemId));

// get from, to, subject, and body from your aspx page and use to construct mail message
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

// create attachment from current item
Stream ms = new MemoryStream(item.File.OpenBinary());
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, item.File.Name));

// send email
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("yourSMTPserver");
smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer Laurie. I will try that out asap. Does this work as a sandbox solution? I don't have farm access in the enviroment where I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom WF Activity : "SharePoint 2010 - Send Email With Attachment" : http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/